# Loading hits in separate sections based on attribute in instantsearch.js

Tags: javascript, algolia, instantsearch.js

Using Algolia instantsearch (JS) - I am attempting to structure the initial load of my hits as follows:

**Heading: Red**

3 posts with the topic 'Red'

**Heading: Blue**

3 posts with the topic 'Blue'

**Heading: Yellow**

3 posts with the topic 'Yellow'

As soon as any query or faceting is performed, the headings should disappear and the results be based on the entire index.

I've looked at initialUiState and the configure widget, but I can't find a way to achieve what I am looking for.

Is there a way, other than having to create separate indices?

Comment: something like https://codesandbox.io/s/ol2ry43w15 ?

Comment: Almost @cmgchess - but when I'm searching there, is it only searching those 2 'types'? The sections are just for the initial load, but there are many more 'types' in the full index that should be queried when searching

Comment: no it seems to have filtered out the hits that belong to a certain type . It is searching for everything with active=1 filter in this example. `const typeTwoHits = hits.filter(hit => {
    return hit.type === "two";
  });`